# Schedule AWS-Lambda with Java and CloudWatch Triggers

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am new to AWS and AWS-Lambdas. I have to create a lambda function to run a cron job in every 10 minutes. I am planning to add a Cloudwatch trigger to trigger the same in every 10 minutes but without any event. I looked up on the internet and found that some event needs to be there to get it running.

I need to get some clarity and leads on below 2 points:

- Can I schedule a job using AWS-Lambda with cloudwatch triggering the same in span of 10 minutes without any events.
- How do one need to make it interact with MySQL databases that have been hosted on AWS.

I have my application built on SpringBoot running on multiple instances with a shared database (single source of truth). I have devised everything stated above using Spring's in-built scheduler and proper synchronisation on DB level using locks but because of the distributed nature of instances, I have been advised to do the same using lambdas.

Comment: May I ask why you cannot use Cloudwatch events?

Comment: I wanted to but doesn't know how to do it. That is why looking for resources or tutorials on the internet.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass ScheduledEvent object to the handleRequest() of the lambda.

> handleRequest(ScheduledEvent event, Contex context)

Configure a cron job that runs every 10 minutes in your cloudwatch template (if using cloudformation). This will make sure to trigger your lambda after every 10 min.

Make sure to add below mentioned dependency to your pom.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Method 2:**

You can specify something like this in your cloudformation template. This will not require any argument to be passed to your handler(), incase you do not require any event related information. This will automatically trigger your lambda as per your cron job.

```
"ScheduledRule": {
        "Type": "AWS::Events::Rule",
        "Properties": {
            "Description": "ScheduledRule",
            "ScheduleExpression": {
                "Fn::Join": [
                    "",
                    [
                        "cron(",
                        {
                            "Ref": "ScheduleCronExpression"
                        },
                        ")"
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "State": "ENABLED",
            "Targets": [
                {
                    "Arn": {
                        "Fn::GetAtt": [
                            "LAMBDANAME",
                            "Arn"
                        ]
                    },
                    "Id": "TargetFunctionV1"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "PermissionForEventsToInvokeLambdaFunction": {
        "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
        "Properties": {
            "FunctionName": {
                "Ref": "NAME"
            },
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "Principal": "events.amazonaws.com",
            "SourceArn": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "ScheduledRule",
                    "Arn"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does event encapsulate some data? Most importantly, I do not require any input for my task to get executed. So basically a cloud watch trigger is an event for me and ScheduledEvent is class designated for such cloudwatch event requests?

Comment: Then there is no need pass any arguments. If you are using cloudformation, you can simply specify in the template the ScheduledEvent which is nothing but an event rule and can configure your cron job accordingly. Also remember giving permissions to cloudwatch to invoke your lambda function

Comment: @jatinmahajan do remember to vote up or down to an answer here. This is how we show our gratitude here. And also if an answer serves your purpose mark it as accepted as it helps other people as well.

Comment: I will do the same once your solution works for me. And +1 for the effort sir. I will let you know once i try this.

Comment: we are all programmers here mate. No sir :) Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to run a cronjob from cloudwatch event is the only option.
- If you don't want to use cloudwatch events then go ahead with EC2 instance. But EC2 will cost you more than the cloudwatch event.

*Note:* Cloudwatch events rule steup is just like defining cronjob in crontab in any linux system, nothing much. In linux serevr you will define everything as a RAW one but here its just an UI based one.

Comment: What is an event is exactly my dilemma. I just need the job to get executed after 10 minutes, that's all. How can I do that using cloudwatch?

I have seen videos on the internet wherein they use some string/json to trigger/test it on the console. Can it be tested just by clicking on test button and without specifying any input?

Comment: That string/json is the input for your lambda. If you don't want any inputs to perform then leave it as empty

Comment: if i leave it empty then will it be triggered by cloudwatch event by default?

Comment: Yes, it does. Simply fill _event source_ or _schedule_ under event source & configure your lambda in target section. And in the next screen give name to your rule that's it.

Comment: public String handleRequest(SimpleLambdaMessage message, Context context) {}
It waits for SimpleLambdaMessage to trigger it as per my understanding, but in my scenario, I dont want any request but just want to trigger it after 10 minutes. How can i handle that? I am really sorry about the delay in response.

Comment: Your understanding about lambda is correct that's how AWS also documented in lambda segment. But in [this] (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html) document there is no need of input params for lambda. First ensure that your lambda is triggered from CW event or not in CW logs. If you encounters any error let me know the error then we try to solve your hurdle.